# How can I switch from one Angular 2 material tabs to another in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two tabs and two buttons

```
<md-tab-group>
<md-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
<button md-button (click)="showTab1()">Show Tab 1</button>
 <button md-button (click)="showTab2()">Show Tab 2</button>
```

I need the function showTab1() to switch to tab 1 if I am on Tab 1 and showTab2() to be executed if the button is clicked. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `[selectedIndex]` **@Input** for `mat-tab-group`:

**Component:**

```
selectedIndex = 0;

selectTab(index: number): void {
  this.selectedIndex = index;
}
```

**Template:**

```
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex">
  <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

<button mat-button (click)="selectTab(0)">Show Tab 1</button>
<button mat-button (click)="selectTab(1)">Show Tab 2</button>
```

<kbd>[**STACKBLITZ DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mxhaho-6mkbrb)</kbd>

... or you can create a reference to the `mat-tab-group` and manipulate it directly in template:

```
<mat-tab-group #tabGroup>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

<button mat-button (click)="tabGroup.selectedIndex = 0">Show Tab 1</button>
<button mat-button (click)="tabGroup.selectedIndex = 1">Show Tab 2</button>
```

<kbd>[**STACKBLITZ DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mxhaho-cgz3zd)</kbd>

Comment: i couldn't use component interaction with the selected answer, that one worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to declare a variable, for example `tab: number  = 1` . Then you can create your template like:

```
<md-tab-group>
<md-tab *ngIf="tab==1" label="Tab 1">Content 1</md-tab>
  <md-tab *ngIf="tab==2" label="Tab 2">Content 2</md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
<button md-button (click)="tab=1">Show Tab 1</button>
 <button md-button (click)="tab=2">Show Tab 2</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @ZanattMan

Comment: It hide the tab, but we have to so the tab and active when the user clicks on next.

Answer (score 0):

in TS

```
  @ViewChild('tabGroup') tabGroup;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.selected_tab_label = this.tabGroup._allTabs._results[this.selectedIndex].textLabel;
  }
```